# How to react data changes in vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to build a component that should update the string using setInterval.

Here is the code of the component.

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      offers: [
        '1!',
        '2!',
        '3!',
      ],
      current_index: 0,
      indexInterval: null,
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.updateToastIndex()
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.indexInterval)
  },
  methods: {
    updateToastIndex() {
      const indexInterval = setInterval(() => {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          if (this.current_index === 2) {
            this.current_index = 0
            console.log(this.offers[this.current_index], 'changedprev')
          } else {
            this.current_index = this.current_index + 1
            console.log(this.offers[this.current_index], 'changed')
          }
        })
      }, 1000)
      this.indexInterval = indexInterval
    },
  },
}
</script>
<template>
  <div>{{ offers[current_index] }}</div>
</template>
```

I can see the current_index in updateToastIndex function getting updated but current_index in template is not getting updated.

Please suggest some solution

Comment: I tested your code. It updates the inner text of ```<div>``` tag in your template! What is the problem?

Comment: I also tested and found no issues.  maybe something else in your app is breaking during runtime and stopping your component code from running.  are there any errors in your browser's dev console?

Comment: I have had reactivity issues when importing code from another project directory that has it's own node_modules, and pulling in 2 different versions of vue.